# The ensure_future() does not appear to execute

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'm using asyncio to create a python back-end service, and I'm a novice.Execute to ensure_future() method, I use to set breakpoints to see that there is no jump to execute subroutines. This subroutine should have created a cache for subsequent programs to use, but I don't know when it will be executed.When I access the route on the web page, the program needs to use this cache, but the cache has not been created yet.
I would appreciate it if you could give me some advice.

server.py

```
app = Sanic(name='flyingflower_public')
app.add_route(asr_view, '/ebrose/asr', methods=["GET"])
app.add_route(tts_view, '/ebrose/tts', methods=["GET"])
app.add_route(pivot_view, '/ebrose/pivot', methods=["GET"])

cachebuilder = CacheBuilder()
asyncio.ensure_future(cachebuilder.runner())  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8000")
```

These are the methods that cachebuilder.runner() needs to execute

```
async def sentence_word_association_cacher(self, limit=1024):
    sentence_word_ids = await self._get_sentence_words_association(limit)
    table_words = dict(await self._get_table_word())
    if sentence_word_ids:
        mapping = dict([(table_words[word_id], sentence_ids.split(","))
                        for word_id, sentence_ids in sentence_word_ids if sentence_ids])
        redis_cli = await self._redis_conn()
        result = await redis_cli.set(POETRY_CACHE_KEY, pack(mapping))
        redis_cli.close()
        await redis_cli.wait_closed()
        return result

async def build_cache(self):
    # refresh cache on time
    while True:
        _Logger.info("{0} [refresh cache]: sentence_word_association => start".format(
            time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))))
        try:
            await self.sentence_word_association_cacher(limit=100)
        except:
            _Logger.info(traceback.print_exc())
        _Logger.info("{0} [refresh cache]: sentence_word_association => success!".format(
            time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))))
        await asyncio.sleep(REFRESH_PERIOD)   # refresh the cache / minutes

async def runner(self):
    await self.build_cache()
```

This is the error message

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<CacheBuilder.runner() running at d:\AndroidStudioProject\yghkdr-flyingflower_public-master\flyingflower_public1.3\flyingflower\cache_build.py:154>>
C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:604: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'CacheBuilder.runner' 
was never awaited
  self._ready.clear()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS1oY.png)

Comment: Is that the whole error message? I would expect an exception to be raised for calling `asyncio.create_task()` at top-level because it is not allowed to call that function outside of a running event loop.

Comment: Yes, This is all the error messages.

Comment: You could try replacing `asyncio.create_task(...)` with `asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(...)`.

Comment: When I replaced it with 'asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(cachebuilder.runner())', there are some mistakes here, and I put them in my description

Comment: I'm sorry, but the image you provided (without even bothering to enter a description) is not helpful. It might indicate an issue in your IDE/tooling setup that has nothing to do with asyncio, but possibly with mismatched Python versions or something like that.